# How to execute .SQL script on SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to find out how to run a script in C# to create tables and data for a SQL Server CE database. I'm getting the following error when `ExecutingNonQuery` off of command:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = USE ]

Code:

```
public static void CreateDatabase()
{
    string connStr = "Data Source='C:\\DataBases/MyDatabase.sdf'; LCID=1033; Case Sensitive = TRUE";

    if (File.Exists(@"C:\\DataBases\MyDatabase.sdf"))
        File.Delete(@"C:\\Databases\MyDatabase.sdf");

    SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStr);
    engine.CreateDatabase();

    string originalDatabaseScriptFile = Helpers.Instance.GetAppPath() + "ApplicationHelpers\\MyDatabase.sql";

    //run script
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(originalDatabaseScriptFile);
    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

    SqlCeConnection sqlCeConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
    sqlCeConnection.Open();

    SqlCeCommand ceCommand = new SqlCeCommand(script, sqlCeConnection);
    ceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Get error here

    engine.Dispose();
}
```

The script I use works for SQL Server Express (`.mdf`) but I want to use for SQL Server CE (`.sdf`)

Any advice on what could be going wrong? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: **SHOW US** the script! SQL Server CE is limited is several ways: it has only a small subset of datatypes, and it's T-SQL implementation is limited, too (e.g. you cannot execute more than 1 statement in a single script)

Comment: My SQL Script is too big to break down into separate statements. I changed back to using .\SQLExpress